# Using C# object in razor view page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have this rows of c# code in View razor page:

```
@{
    List<UserContact> userContacts = ViewBag.contacts;
    String contacts = Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/Contacts.cshtml", userContacts).ToHtmlString();
}
```

I want to use the content of contacts variable in JavaScript function since the contacts is a C# object I cant use this variable in JavaScript function.

Is there any way to use contacts variable in Javascript function?
Maybe since the type is string it can be converted to JavaScript variable?

Comment: in a script: `var partialHtml = '@contacts';`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@` directives like you would normally do. You can print it using `Html.Raw`:

```
var x = /* this is javascript */
@{
    ...

    @Html.Raw(contacts)
}
```

Or just call `@Html.Partial` directly:

```
var x = /* this is javascript */
@{
    ...

    @Html.Partial(...)
}
```

Or declare it here:

```
@{
    ...

    string contacts = @Html.Partial(...)
}
```

And use it later:

```
@contacts
```

Comment: I need to pass the content of the contacts object to the parent  view razor page, for this purpose I need to convert the C# object to JavaScript object.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is, you only need to render it inside a script block. Try this:

```
<script>

    var contacts = '@contacts';
    alert(contacts);

</script>
```